# Почему не отправляются данные с AJAX-скриптом?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, есть форма отправки данных в БД. **Без скрипта работает нормально**, а со скриптом ничего не происходит. В консоли разр-ка Form Data все данные есть, и 200й код приходит, но в БД не добавляется.

PHP:

```
<?php
  $data = $_POST;
  if ( isset($data['add']) )
  { $posts = R::dispense('posts');      
  $posts->head = $data['head'];
  $posts->desc = $data['desc'];
  R::store($posts);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="FormID">
  <input type="text" name="head" required />
  <input type="text" name="head" required />
  <button type="submit" name="add">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#FormID").submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $("#FormID").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      c = "hello";
      $('#FormStatus').text(c);
    }
  });
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть проблема с CORS? Смотрите консоль

Comment: Кнопка `add` не передается на сервер. Это вы могли бы увидеть через `print_r($_POST)`, Но лучше неделю одно и то же спрашивать)